# Is it correct to create array of strings this way in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, malloc

Is it correct to create array of *n string*s this way in c++?

```
string *a = (string*)malloc(sizeof(string)*n);
...
free(a);
```

Comment: It's usually not "correct" to use `malloc` in C++ - see `new` as the direct counterpart.

Comment: No, never. use std::vector instead.

Comment: It might work, but you'd be better off avoiding use of malloc, or new, and using a std::container of your choice.

Comment: what would possibly be sizeof(string)???

Comment: @PSS The size of an `std::string` object.

Comment: You haven't created an array of strings; you've created a block of memory that's big enough for an array of n strings. You have to use placement new afterwards to actually put the strings in that memory, and call the right delete operator afterwards (before your free).

Comment: @ChrisCM : there's no 'might work' here. It won't work, as the objects are never created or freed.

Comment: @Roddy: Fair enough, didn't really bother to read it or care what it does.  Saw C++ tag and malloc, and directed him towards a better solution.  While I'm not familiar with malloc, I imagine you could force this solution to work with memcpy, making this(depending on what the ... represents) valid code... terrible code, but valid, hence a correctly stated "might".  Never say never when it comes to a programmer's determination to do bad things!

Comment: @ChrisCM - Understood, but you'd struggle with memcpy here! The problem with std::strings is that they don't hold the characters 'within' the object, but instead hold a pointer to a dynamically allocated array of chars. The memory returned from malloc might (if you're very, very lucky) match an 'empty' string. (Null pointer, zero length, etc..) BUT : by calling 'free' instead of 'delete', any subsequently allocated memory would be leaked. Again, copying them with `memcpy()` would do a 'shallow copy`, with two strings pointing at the same block of chars- a recipe for disaster!

Comment: @Roddy: I kind of want to do this now, just to see what terrible situations I can create by trying to do this...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Your strings are never actually constructed. Unlike `new`, `malloc()` does not construct objects - it just allocates memory.

Just use this:

```
  std::string a[n];
```

or,

```
  std::vector<std::string> a;
```

Because C++ strings will dynamically allocate the memory to hold the characters internally, the 'sizeof' a std::string is typically very small (maybe 16 bytes) regardless of the number of characters contained. So (unlike C where string handling often involves extensive malloc/free nightmares) there's typically no need  to dynamically allocate strings.

Comment: Or `std::array<std::string, n> a;` if you have that compile-time constant.

Comment: @chris, yes, but if you have n at compile time, then `std::string a[n];` is hard to fault.

Answer (score 15):

No, that is incorrect. `malloc` does not call the constructors for `std::string`, all `malloc` does is allocate the memory and leaves the memory unintialized. At the very least you will want to use `new`. However, the best way to create an array of strings is to use `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<std::string> a(n);
```

Now you no longer have to worry about memory management.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
string *a = new string[SIZE];
```

And to free it up:

```
delete [] a;
```

To do it without pointers it is much easier:

```
string a[n];
```

No delete needed

Comment: You probably wanted to put * before `a`

Comment: *"Note that the individual items of the array are uninitialized"* -- What do you mean by this?  With your call to `new string[SIZE]`, the strings are definitely initialized, unless you're using a non-standard definition of "uninitialized".